# DB Procedure to Dynamically update DB columns

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dynamic-sql

Requirement is to update in db column only those column which are edited from frontend.
Logic i am using is to send 2 arrays from java code to DB procedire.

1st array is: Column_array which contains column names which have to be updated.

&

2nd array : value_array which contains the values of columns respoctive to the column_array.

From JAVA:

```
Array value_array = ((OracleConnection) dbConnection).createOracleArray("STRING_ARRAY",
                valueList.toArray());

        Array param_array = ((OracleConnection) dbConnection).createOracleArray("STRING_ARRAY",
                            paramList.toArray());

 stmt = dbConnection.prepareCall(SqlConstants.UPDATE_SUBSCRIBER_CONFIG_IN_BOLTES);//
            stmt.setLong(1, 3628);
            stmt.setLong(2, 3629);
            stmt.setLong(3, 3632);
            stmt.setArray(4, param_array);
            stmt.setArray(5, value_array);
            int count = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

NOW at DB side:

how can i iterate over this list to update and set this in SET clause???

```
 PROCEDURE update_subscriber_config (
    p_app_id        VARCHAR2,
    p_service_id     VARCHAR2,
    p_pubsub_id       VARCHAR2,
    column_list     string_array,
    value_list      string_array
)
    AS
BEGIN

FOR a IN 1..column_list.count LOOP
        update  bolt_oracle_pubsub_config set 
            column_list(a)=value_list(a),
             ...how to do iteration here???

      where  APP_ID = p_app_id AND SERVICE_ID =  p_service_id AND PUBSUB_ID = p_pubsub_id;
       END LOOP;

END update_subscriber_config;
```

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Why not create a dynamic SQL statement String where you update only the columns that were passed in in your list?

Comment: Agreed. Dynamically create an UPDATE statement in your code.

Comment: In the update SQL, update the columns which are having values, others would be empty or NULL. Why use two arrays to check which columns are updated?

Comment: We have to use DB procedures. How can i acheive it, can u please help me write sql.

Comment: @NehaGoswami I have added an answer, in my honest opinion avoid the array which is having the column names and avoid the dynamic SQL for the simple reason which is you would be able to achieve the expected output with a simple update statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use dynamic SQL to assemble bespoke update statements. It will look something like this:

```
PROCEDURE update_subscriber_config (
    p_app_id        VARCHAR2,
    p_service_id     VARCHAR2,
    p_pubsub_id       VARCHAR2,
    column_list     string_array,
    value_list      string_array
)
AS
   stmt varchar2(32767);
BEGIN

    stmt := 'update  bolt_oracle_pubsub_config set ';

    FOR a IN 1..column_list.count LOOP
        if a != 1 then
           stmt := stmt ||', ';
        end if;
        stmt := stmt || column_list(a) ||'=''' ||value_list(a)||'''';
       END LOOP;

       stmt := stmt ||
             ' where  APP_ID = :p1 AND SERVICE_ID = :p2 AND PUBSUB_ID = :p3';
      execute immediate stmt using p_app_id , p_service_id , p_pubsub_id;
END update_subscriber_config;
```

This is a very crude implemnentation, as it assumes all the passed columns can be treated as strings. If your table has numeric or date columns you should think about handling data conversion, because that could become a problem.

Dynamic SQL is hard because it turns compilation errors into runtime errors. In your case you have a piece of code which potentially executes a different update statement every time you call it. So testing this procedure is a total nightmare. This means you have a heavy dependency on the front end passing  arrays with valid contents.

Comment: Amazing!! Thanks a lot. This code works for me perfecttly!! :) In my case i will only get strings.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution which was simpler than array iteration.

Solution is to use COALESCE method.

```
 PROCEDURE TEST (
      p_app_id       NUMBER,
    p_service_id   NUMBER,
    p_pubsub_id    NUMBER,
    p_pubsub_name       VARCHAR2,
    p_host              VARCHAR2,
    p_user_name           VARCHAR2,
    p_auth_key              VARCHAR2
)
    AS
BEGIN

     update bolt_elastic_pubsub_config set 
      PUBSUB_NAME = coalesce(p_pubsub_name, PUBSUB_NAME),
       HOST = coalesce(p_host, HOST),
        USER_NAME = coalesce(p_user_name, USER_NAME),
        AUTH_KEY = coalesce(p_auth_key, AUTH_KEY)
     where  APP_ID = p_app_id AND SERVICE_ID =  p_service_id AND PUBSUB_ID = p_pubsub_id;

END TEST;
```

Comment: Great, coalesce or NVL would help with simple update statements.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try avoiding one of the arrays which are the column array as Oracle SQL would tolerate if the value is null.

The below is the pseudo code.

```
PROCEDURE update_subscriber_config (p_app_id             VARCHAR2,
                                    p_service_id         VARCHAR2,
                                    p_pubsub_id          VARCHAR2,
                                    p_first_column       VARCHAR2,
                                    p_second_column      VARCHAR2,
                                    --column_list     string_array,
                                    i_array           IN my_array_type)
AS
BEGIN
   FORALL i IN 1 .. i_array.COUNT
      UPDATE bolt_oracle_pubsub_config
         SET your_first_column =
                TREAT (i_array (i) AS my_array_type).column_array_name,
             your_second_column =
                TREAT (i_array (i) AS my_array_type).second_column_array_name
       WHERE     APP_ID = p_app_id
             AND SERVICE_ID = p_service_id
             AND PUBSUB_ID = p_pubsub_id;

END update_subscriber_config;
```

If any of the columns which are stated in the update SQL is empty, it would be null or empty in the table after executing the update. Having said that, ensure all `NOT NULL` or mandatory columns are populated.

I would reckon to avoid the dynamic SQL update due to error-prone. If you achieve the results without using dynamic SQL, then why the hassle with dynamic SQL update.